# Kohana 3.2 ORM validation and form validations

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3.2

Since last one year, I worked on a maintenance project in Kohan 3.0.7. While I was looking to the latest version (3.2), I came across ORM validation which I had not noticed while I worked with Kohana 3.0.7. In my project, I used form validation and validated all the forms in model. While reading, http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/orm/examples/validation, I found that validation rule for  extra field "Confirm Password" is being added in the controller itself. So, I want to know -

Can we move the ORM validation rules to model files completely ? if we can then how it can be done ?

Does the **values** method take care of sql injections ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't and shouldn't move model validation to the controller.
In the example you provided they used so called "extra validation".
Take a look at the save [method API](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/ORM#save) - it takes optional `Validation` argument that is used later on in `check` method to validate additional logic (like e.g. passwords matching).
The reason is that you don't have a field in your model called "password_matching" (then you could just write this rule in `rules` function ;)), so you need to use external validation for such case.
Another example of using external validation would be uploading a file and, based on the upload result, doing operations on your ORM model.

Yes, ORM is SQL injection safe as it uses `Query Builder` which is also safe (except of `DB::expr` which should be used with extra care).

Comment: hey, thanks for the clarification. I know we shouldn't move the model validation to controller, actually, my intention for this question was, if it is possible to keep the controller free of external validation as well. But, you clarified it. Can you add a word for sql injections question ?